# Сразу закрывается форма visual studio c++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio

При запуске отладки открывается форма на 1 миллисекунду, и сразу закрывается помогите пожалуйста.

ConsoleApplication1.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

   return 0;
}
```

MyForm.h

```
#pragma once

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^ comboBox1;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->comboBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(89, 143);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this->comboBox1->FormattingEnabled = true;
            this->comboBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(89, 55);
            this->comboBox1->Name = L"comboBox1";
            this->comboBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(121, 21);
            this->comboBox1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->comboBox1->SelectedIndexChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    }
    };
}
```

Comment: Ну так функция main выполняет `return 0;` и все.

Comment: а что должна подскажи?

Comment: Все что вы напишите, то и выполнит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `main` для программы WinForms выглядит так:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
int main(array < String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(0);
    ConsoleApplication1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Судя по названию, у вас проект создан как Console Application, и в нем может болтаться коммандное окно. Чтобы это исправить, используйте параметр линкера /Subsystem.